# Stripe.apiKey not resolving in Android

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe as a payment processor in my Android app and trying to charge a card as described by the documentation: https://stripe.com/docs/charges

My issue specifically is that it can not resolve `Stripe.apiKey`, or `can not resolve symbol apiKey`

The code that I'm implementing from the documentation:

```
// Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
Stripe.apiKey = "sk_test_********************";//this is where i hit a wall

// Token is created using Stripe.js or Checkout!
// Get the payment token submitted by the form:
String token = request.getParameter("stripeToken");

// Charge the user's card:
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("amount", 1000);
params.put("currency", "usd");
params.put("description", "Example charge");
params.put("source", token);

Charge charge = Charge.create(params);
```

I have also imported `import com.stripe.android.*;` at the top of my file.

In my Gradle file I have imported the Stripe libraries:

```
compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:2.0.2'
```

Why isn't Android able to resolve `Stripe.apiKey`?

Comment: Make sure you have used `com.stripe.Stripe` instead of some other package

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code you provided is *server-side* Java code for [creating a charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) using a token. It is not meant to be used from an Android application.

A payment flow with Stripe is divided in two steps:

- client-side, in your frontend code, you collect and tokenize the user's payment information (using [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) or [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js) for a web application, or the [iOS](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios) / [Android](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android) SDKs for a native mobile application)
- server-side, in your backend code, you use the resulting token in an API request, e.g. to [create a charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) or [a customer object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer).

The first step is done with your publishable API key (`pk_...`). The second step is done with your secret API key (`sk_...`).

You must never share the secret API key with your frontend code, otherwise an attacker could retrieve it and use it to issue API requests on your behalf.

Answer (score 1):

To solve `Stripe.apikey cannot resolve`, change `Stripe.apiKey` to

```
com.stripe.Stripe.apiKey = "Your secret";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try: `Stripe stripe = new Stripe("pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh");`

For more info check out: https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android#credit-card-form

Comment: It should be Stripe stripe = new Stripe(context, "pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh");

Answer (score 0):

Import this dependency in gradle file.

```
implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-java:22.18.0'
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76216386/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).